dyld: Symbol not found: VisionKit32ImageAnalysisInteractionDelegate
My project was running fine on Xcode 14.x. It's also running fine with Xcode 15.x and iOS 17.
But without making any changes, I'm getting a crash on startup and this error with Xcode 15.x and iOS 16:
dyld[56820]: Symbol not found: _$s9VisionKit32ImageAnalysisInteractionDelegatePAAE22textSelectionDidChangeyyAA0cdE0CF
  Referenced from: <9AB4D482-F7DC-3930-97FD-BEA5B0E7FDAC> /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E39921F-4570-4A7E-BC4C-BD47C2EECDFF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5683B911-CCC3-4D97-9EAC-97A8DF01AFBA/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
  Expected in:     <F05E3A17-D74A-3EE2-BC8D-DDCC23E48707> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_20E247/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 16.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/VisionKit.framework/VisionKit

This is my usage of ImageAnalysisInteractionDelegate:
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import VisionKit
import Vision


struct TextRecognition: UIViewRepresentable {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    

    class Coordinator: NSObject, ImageAnalysisInteractionDelegate {
        var parent: TextRecognition

        init(_ parent: TextRecognition) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            
            // ...
        }
        
        // ...
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
}

Anything I can do about this? I tried submitting via Xcode 14, but that’s not possible anymore. It‘s also not possible to revert to the previous build, and adding a new minimum version still leaves the old one active.
So for now it seems I’m stuck with a version that crashes on iOS 16.
